# Mongo project error in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Mongo `project` is giving error when date is in format like `YYYY-01-01`

#### Date in Mongo

```
[pd] => MongoDate Object
    (
        [sec] => 946665000
        [usec] => 0
    )
[pn] => JP2000285176A
```

**PHP date returns**

```
date('Y-m-d',946665000) => 2000-01-01
```

#### MongoDB aggregation

```
db.patents.aggregate({'$match':{'pn':'JP2000285176A'}},{'$project':{'pn':1,'pd':{'$year':'$pd'}}})
```

**Result**

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("530dce78b25d9d526f44e104"),
        "pd" : 1999,
        "pn" : "JP2000285176A"
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Aggregation returns **1999** instead of **2000**

### Update

Unresolved issue

[Timezone support in date operators at query time](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310)

Comment: Can you print the value of "$pd" (entire date object) instead of trying to extract the year, so we know the complete date that's stored in MongoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a timezone related issue.

See [How to agregate by year-month-day on a different timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852095/how-to-agregate-by-year-month-day-on-a-different-timezone) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Like you updated in your question, this issue is already discussed in [SERVER-6310](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310) which will be resolved in version [2.7 desired](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER/fixforversion/10213).

Now,  because all the time is stored in UTC in Mongodb,  you can use `$project` to shift the time to your timezone. To add time there is `$add` and to subtract time there is `$subtract`. Note that the addition/subtraction has to be done in milliseconds[hours*60*60*1000].

For example,  in your case,  since you are from India[+5:30],  you can add 5:30 hrs to UTC[or GMT].

```
db.patents.aggregate(
           {'$match':{'pn':'JP2000285176A'}},
           {'$project':{'pn':1,'pd':{'$year':{$add:['$pd',5.5*60*60*1000]}}}}
)
```

[#REF](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)