# Mongodb aggregate: convert date to another timezone

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, aggregation-framework

I save my transaction with something like :

```
{code: "A", total: 250000, timestamp: ISODate("2016-01-20T23:57:05.771Z")},
{code: "B", total: 300000, timestamp: ISODate("2016-01-20T05:57:05.771Z")}
```

each of transaction has `timestamp` field under UTC timezone in it. Since I live in Jakarta (UTC+7) timezone, I need to add 7 hours to my timestamp before aggregation. Here's my mongo syntax:

```
db.transaction.aggregate(
[
 {
   $project:
     {
       year: { $year: "$timestamp" },
       month: { $month: "$timestamp" },
       day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" }
     }
 }
])
```

It returns:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a01ed143f2fd071793d63b"),
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 20
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a01ed143f2fd071793d63b"),
        "year" : 2016,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 20
    }
```

which is wrong since the first transaction (code `A`), is happened at 21st January, but since it was converted to UTC (-7 Hours), it became `ISODate("2016-01-20T23:57:05.771Z")`

Note: I'm aware [about the same problem over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852095/how-to-agregate-by-year-month-day-on-a-different-timezone), here's what I've been tried so far:

```
db.transaction.aggregate(
[
 {$project: {"timestamp": {$add: [7 * 60 * 60 * 1000]}}},
 {
   $project:
     {
       year: { $year: "$timestamp" },
       month: { $month: "$timestamp" },
       day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" }
     }
 }
])
```

but it returns `can't convert from BSON type NumberDouble to Date` error. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you accept Kevin's answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoDB 3.6 added timezone parameter to the date manipulation operators. See [Kevin's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48535842/3100115)

We can add the "timestamp" to `7 * 60 * 60 * 1000` in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

The following pipeline seems to work in  MongoDB 3.4 or older.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "year": { "$year": { "$add": [ "$timestamp", 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ] } }, 
        "month": { "$month": { "$add": [ "$timestamp", 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ] } }, 
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth": { "$add": [ "$timestamp", 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ] } } 
    } }
])
```

Comment: It's a good solution when you have only one time-zone but will not work for dynamic timezone.

Comment: MongoDB 3.6 now supports this feature, see @Kevin's answer.

Comment: @MKNWebSolutions, You are right, the timezone parameter was added in 3.6. Kevin already got my vote. But this solutions seems to be ok if you haven't upgraded your mongod yet.

Answer (score 41):

As an update, MongoDB 3.6 has a new timezone parameter for date manipulation in the aggregation framework. Most date-related operators accept this optional parameter, see [`$hour`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#exp._S_hour) for one example.

For example, if we have a document where the date is exactly the new year in UTC:

```
> db.test.find()
{"_id": 1, "dt": ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z")}
```

We can display the date in New York timezone:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
        {$project:{
            date:{$dayOfMonth:{date:'$dt',timezone:'America/New_York'}},
            month:{$month:{date:'$dt',timezone:'America/New_York'}},
            year:{$year:{date:'$dt',timezone:'America/New_York'}},
            hour:{$hour:{date:'$dt',timezone:'America/New_York'}}
        }}
    ])
{ "_id": 1, "date": 31, "month": 12, "year": 2017, "hour": 19 }
```

We can also display the date in Sydney timezone:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
        {$project:{
            date:{$dayOfMonth:{date:'$dt',timezone:'Australia/Sydney'}},
            month:{$month:{date:'$dt',timezone:'Australia/Sydney'}},
            year:{$year:{date:'$dt',timezone:'Australia/Sydney'}},
            hour:{$hour:{date:'$dt',timezone:'Australia/Sydney'}}
        }}
    ])
{ "_id": 1, "date": 1, "month": 1, "year": 2018, "hour": 11 }
```

Or could use a single [`$dateToParts`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/)

```
> db.test.aggregate([
        {$project:{
            dateToParts:{$dateToParts:{date:'$dt',timezone:'Australia/Sydney'}}
        }}
    ])
{ "_id": 1, "dateToParts": { "day": 1, "hour": 11, "millisecond": 0, "minute": 0, "month": 1, "second": 0, "year": 2018 } }
```

The timezone description is using the standard [Olson Timezone Identifier string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`$dateToString`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) method with $project to get specified timezone result.

Note this requires a format argument, see [Format Specifiers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#std-label-format-specifiers) for more info.

```
$project:{
     created_at: {
            $dateToString: {
              date: '$createdAt',
              timezone: '+07:00',
              format: '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi sharing my solution used on one of my extracts using mongodb version 3.4 or below and need it to covert from utc to manila time +08:00

see the sample query below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{
   "created_at":{"$dateToString": { "date":{ "$add": [ "$yourtimestampfield", 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ] }, "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"}},
}}])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAIFA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the name of the timezone like so:

```
$project: {  
  releaseDate: {
    $dateToString: {
      date: "$releaseDate",
      timezone: "America/Sao_Paulo",
      format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    }
  }
}
```