# Group by month and year is not working mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

Here is the query,

```
db.getCollection('_ad.insight').aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            date: {
                $lte: ISODate('2018-12-31'),
                $gte: ISODate('2017-01-01')
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            year: {$year: "$date"},
            month: {$month: "$date"},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"},
            date: 1,
            clicks: 1,
            reach: 1 
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                month: "$month",
                year: "$year"
            },
            clicks: {$sum: "$clicks"},
            reach: {$sum: "$reach"},
            date: {$addToSet: "$date"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            month: "$_id.month",
            year: "$_id.year",
            clicks: 1,
            reach: 1,
            date: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

And the response I am getting,

```
/* 1 */
{
    "clicks" : 1096,
    "reach" : 33288,
    "date" : [
        ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-28T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-26T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-24T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-23T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-25T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-29T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-21T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-30T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-20T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-27T00:00:00.000+05:00")
    ],
    "month" : 12,
    "year" : 2017
},

/* 2 */
{
    "clicks" : 1629,
    "reach" : 98113,
    "date" : [
        ISODate("2018-01-05T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-07T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-08T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-06T00:00:00.000+05:00")
    ],
    "month" : 1,
    "year" : 2018
}
```

Sample Collection:
Its a flat structure, contains around 400 fields, but i am showing only those which i am using in query.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5akjbrd51f193455adtrf6fc"),
    "clicks" : 5,
    "reach" : 10 
    "date" : ISODate("2018-01-06T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
    "post_engagement" : 127,
    "post_reactions" : 1,
    "post_shares" : 0,
    "qualificationfailed" : 0,
    "qualificationfailed_conversion_value" : 0
}
```

Desired Output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "clicks" : 1096,
    "reach" : 33288,
    "date" : [
        ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00"),//this shouldn't be here
        ISODate("2017-12-31T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-28T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-26T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-24T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-23T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-25T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-29T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-22T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-21T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-30T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-20T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2017-12-27T00:00:00.000+05:00")
    ],
    "month" : 12,
    "year" : 2017
},

/* 2 */
{
    "clicks" : 1629,
    "reach" : 98113,
    "date" : [
        // ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00") this should be in this group
        ISODate("2018-01-05T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-03T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-07T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-08T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-02T00:00:00.000+05:00"),
        ISODate("2018-01-06T00:00:00.000+05:00")
    ],
    "month" : 1,
    "year" : 2018
}
```

The issue is,
ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00")
as you can see in output document 1, in date array the above mentioned date is on first index.
It shows the "month" : 12 and "year" : 2017 as i am grouping by month and year. 
So my concern is, ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00") should belong to group number 2, that is 2 output document but its showing up in group 1.

I don't know what i am doing wrong, as its a simple pipeline. Please help!!

Comment: can you please paste a sample of collection and desired output?

Comment: Added. Please check now!

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? Can you use 3.6 ?

Comment: @Veeram: Yes using 3.6

Comment: You can use tz to provide the timezone string. Somethign like           `{ $year: {
    date: '$date',
    timezone: "America/Chicago"
} }`. Change to use your timezone identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note that `ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00")` is in **UTC** + 5. This means that this entry has this date 2017-12-31T19:00:00 on UTC time.

Mongo is grouping the dates according to **UTC**.

You might want to check this post for dealing with different timezones
[How to aggregate by year-month-day on a different timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852095/how-to-aggregate-by-year-month-day-on-a-different-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

As Juanín mentioned, $year is by default using UTC time. You can now mention the timezone when you are converting date to string. Refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/index.html

Below will do the job for you.

```
db.getCollection('_ad.insight').aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            date: {
                $lte: ISODate('2018-12-31T00:00:00.000+05:00'),
                $gte: ISODate('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:00')
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            year: {$year: {date: "$date",timezone: "+0500"}},
            month: {$month: {date: "$date",timezone: "+0500"}},
            day: {$dayOfMonth: {date: "$date",timezone: "+0500"}},
            date: 1,
            clicks: 1,
            reach: 1 
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                month: "$month",
                year: "$year"
            },
            clicks: {$sum: "$clicks"},
            reach: {$sum: "$reach"},
            date: {$addToSet: "$date"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            month: "$_id.month",
            year: "$_id.year",
            clicks: 1,
            reach: 1,
            date: 1
        }
    }
]);
```